A Challenging Tetris - Dekadoku
Now I'm sharing this new and very difficult Dekadoku puzzle, which is truly beautiful. The color is decorative.
You already know the rules:

Place all the combinations of two-digit numbers (from 00 to 99).
In each row or column, no number can have the same tens digit.
In each row or column, no number can have the same units digit.

Previous posts:
A new nameless game
DEKADOKU, the new challenge

Text version:
68 96 51       20 87    72 34
      17    39 93       50 85
75                           
59       67 28 74       03 12
40          07             76
06    23          42 77    90
      04          79 82      
      70 56                43
81             69       36 27
14 37 62    71 45 26    98   


Does the Tetris thing enter the solution process in any way, or is it just a reference to the shape of the initial clues?

It is just a reference. The color is decorative.

Solved Dekadoku below. That was a nice one. Thank you for posting it!





 First, I started with taking inventory of which numbers had already been used. After that, it is basically always the same steps - look at lines and columns either in the dekadoku or in the numbers inventory and figure out, which lines have only a few unknowns. Revisit older/incomplete information as needed.

 Actually this is a pretty straightforward puzzle, no guessing or intricate processes needed.

 I have marked all lines I looked at individually in the steps below. Numbers above and to the left of the dekadoku indicate known numbers with unknown positions in the respective line or column.

 Numbers below and to the right indicate first digits and second digits still missing in that row or column but without enough information to know the exact number yet.

 Numbers in the inventory are marked yellow if the position is not yet known exactly, but a row or column is known, in white if they have been added in this step and in grey if they have been known previously.
 





